# Tools for helping to learn openings by heart

Tags: opening, learning

Is there any tool that can help us learn openings by heart? I tried to use Fritz but without success.

Answer (score 7):

Two well-known programs that are meant specifically to aid in the memorization of opening variations are

1. [Chess Position Trainer](http://www.chesspositiontrainer.com/index.php/en/)
2. [Chess Openings Wizard](http://www.bookup.com/) (formerly *Bookup*)

Both programs are designed to recognize and handle [transpositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_%28chess%29) seamlessly, and they allow a player to drill all the positions that are part of any repertoires that he or she inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Chessable is famous for learning chess openings by the MoveTrainer space repetition. Check out MoveTrainer at https://www.chessable.com/movetrainer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use Chessable. It makes you play through all the variations when you review a course, and there are a bunch of free courses on there that are excellent for getting started with an opening.

The Short & Sweet series is pretty good. Sam Shankland, Anish Giri, and a bunch of other masters have some good S&S courses that are 20-30 lines or so, as they are just a demo version of the massive "Lifetime Repertoires" series. They're great for club players.

There are also free courses published by community members that are more extensive. I used the "Ruy Lopez: Masterclass Edition" course to learn a new opening that I now enjoy immensely.

If those aren't enough for you, you can find some pretty low-priced courses on more or less anything you want. Lifetime Repertoires courses are expensive and have huge numbers of lines, but there are smaller ones you can get for a lower price. For example, I am an owner of "Rafael Leitao's Najdorf Sicilian" which was around $5 and has 150 lines or so.